# How to dynamic generate this layout and implements this UI ?(Android)

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, user-interface, tabs

I have this layout to do.

![enter image description here][1]

But I don't know how to implement is the better method.

Is it use tabhost or dynamic generate layout to implement?

I have tried to use tabhost, but I can't change the tabhosts `y` position.

I use dynamic layout, but I don't know how to use dynamic generation to arrange this layout position.

The layout is click "C" will show 7 sub tab (or sub layout) offer user to click. then the content will show below.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to create the layout dynamically, then so be it, but it makes sense to separate the code from the UI, which is why XML is preferred for layouts.  You could have a vertical `LinearLayout` of horizontal `LinearLayouts`.  You can use weights to guarantee how much space each element takes up.